# add conditon on whereNotIn() laravel

Tags: laravel, if-statement, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am try to do is check if the booking is b/n request check_in and check_out date. if so exclude the booking with booked status =1.

```
$room->bookings()->where(function ($query) use ($check_in, $check_out, $statusCollect) {
                       $query->where('check_in','<=',$check_out) 
                             ->where('check_out','>=',$check_in)
                       ->whereNotIn('book_status_id', $statusCollect)
 });
```

but the problem is this query filter all inside table. how I can I use if statement in whereNotIn() or is there is other method.

what I need is if the check_in<=$check_in and $check_out >=check_out then give me booking table row then check the bookstatus, if it pass get me the row.

I hope I don't make it complicated:).
 thanks

Comment: Could you pls add your table structure and example of desired result ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//controller
//first get data if data get then update the status 
 $data=$room->bookings()->where(function ($query) use ($check_in, $check_out) {
                       $query->where('check_in','<=',$check_out) 
                             ->where('check_out','>=',$check_in)
                       });
if(!empty($data) && $data!=''){
//you can use your table primary id to update the status
$modelObj=new model_name();
$updateArray=$modelObj->updatedById($data->id[
'book_status_id'=>statusCollect
]);
}

//model
function updatedById($id,$statusCollect){
return $this->where('id',$id)->update($statusCollect);
}
```

Comment: thanks for fast reply. i am not trying to update. i just want to before filter check the $check_in and $check_out  are b/n booking check_in and check_out. is that true then remove me booking with book status_id of 1